# Reading jpg texture for OpenGL in c

Tags: c, opengl

This is a 1024 x 512 jpg. 
The size variable returns 84793. 
 One thing that I don't understand is the 84793 as the size of the file when 1024 * 512 = 524288.
 I would think this would be * 3 since 3 channels per pixel. 
The count variable is returning 65. 
Right now I'm getting a access violation reading location on this line when I'm setting OpenGL texture parameters:
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texPtr);
Where texWidth and texHeight where the width and height from below.

Here's what I have currently:

```
int width = 1024;
int height = 512;
long size  = 0;
GLubyte * data;
FILE * file;
char name[100];
int count;

int test;

strcpy(name, filename);
// open texture data
file = fopen( name, "r" );
if ( file == NULL )
{
fputs ("File error",stderr); 
exit (1);
 }
 fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_END);
 size = ftell( file );
 rewind(file);
// allocate buffer
data = (unsigned char *)malloc( sizeof(char)*size );

count = (int) fread (data,sizeof(unsigned char) ,size,file);
fclose( file );

// allocate a texture name
glGenTextures( 1, &dayGLTexture );

initTexture(dayGLTexture, width, height, data);
```

Comment: I think you'll have to decode the JPEG before you can use it with OpenGL, which only supports certain compressed image formats. Your size difference also comes from this - JPEG is compressed.

Comment: thank you so much. this led me to converting to bmp and I'm starting to get results. If you answer this question, I will accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL does not process JPEG compression, and it also doesn't process JPEG image file formats. You cannot just take a file on the disk, blast it into memory and hand it off to OpenGL. You have to read the file format, process it into a form that OpenGL can actually read, and then give it to OpenGL.

There are [a number of libraries](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_loading) you can use to do this, for various different image formats. You should also read up about [how OpenGL understands the pixel data you give it](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer), as well as understand what the [internal image format parameter](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) means.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass image files directly to OpenGL directly. Image files are containers. The data they contain must be unpacked and decoded first. There are some file formats which *may* contain the data in a form directly digestable by OpenGL (flat data), among them TGA and BMP.

However you should **NEVER** pass data of a file directly to some API (except if you're building a file transfer or copy program).

Reading an image file always requires the following steps:

- Reading and interpreting the metadata (either a header, or a tail, or both).
- Preparing intermediary buffers and the reading/decoding process based on the metadata information.
- Read the data from the file and decode it (for flat files this may still require some field swizzling, bitmasking and color correction). Compressed data must be decompressed first. *JPEG is a lossy compression scheme*
- Pass the data to OpenGL, or just keep it around in a buffer for later use.